# How to fix Pyinstaller Attribute Error? Python Py Qt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have a Python file  which is work properly but 
When I triyng to convert py to exe there are a lot of errors like this :

```
104794 WARNING: Cannot read QLibraryInfo output: raised Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when decoding:
PySide2/__init__.py: Unable to import shiboken2 from , C:\Users\Vlad\Desktop\Sysan, C:\Users\Vlad, c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages, c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.zip, c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\DLLs, c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib, c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32, C:\Users\Vlad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Vlad\Sysan7_2_last.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 502, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 410, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 377, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 793, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PySide2.py", line 18, in <module>
    collect_system_data_files(pyside2_library_info.location['PrefixPath'],
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self, name)
  File "c:\users\vlad\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 89, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError

C:\Users\Vlad>
```

My code contains a lot of modules such as Networkx, Plotly, Py Qt5, may be problem with it.

Comment: Which version of pyinstaller are you using?